# How to get rid of Mathematica 10's help tooltips?

Tags: interface

Since *Mathematica 10* every time your mouse cursor appears above some function or even variable, an annoying tooltip appears offering help:

[image]

I've become quite used to *Mathematica* now and I don't need these tooltips  everywhere every second, and I can just as easily click the function and press <kbd>F1</kbd> to get help.

I've tried almost every promising-looking option in `Edit->Preferences->Interface` page, but I couldn't remove these tooltips.

So, how do I finally get rid of them?

Comment: Oh, indeed it's a duplicate